# Getting Wrong Screen Sizes in iPhone 6/6+

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscreen

I am getting wrong screen size in iPhone 6 and 6+ by using

```
[UIScreen mainScreen].nativeBounds
```

and

```
[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds
```

In both case , i am getting wrong screen size.

So, I have added launch screen for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+ then I get correct size of screen in iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+.

But another problem is that My App UI displaying wrong. All Screens of app left right padding. See below image :

[image]

If I remove launch screen for iPhone 6 and 6+ then App UI is displaying right as displaying before like below image :

[image]

In above image, no right padding.

I have also check by adding launch screen but that also getting wrong screen sizes.

**Note :** **I have used AutoResize in app and It is working good in whole app.**

I have also do so much googling to find out actual problem but unfortunately can't get it.  Thanks so much in advance If anyone help to sort out that problem.

Comment: Hai are you using autolayout? or autoresizing ? or control it from code?

Comment: I have used AutoResizing. See in Question

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21668673/2710486) answer might be helpful to understand the issue.

Comment: oh great!. If you are use autolayout this is so simple. but fixed in auto resizing which is not fully applicable. Somaetimes you have to handle it through code like you should fix the origin for only iphone 6 or 6+

Comment: @S.Karthik thanks for that. If i change it from autoresize to autolayout then it takes many days. because my app has almost more than 50 screens. So i don't want to change it to autolayout.

Comment: @zcui93. I have already see that link. But can't sort out problem.

Comment: @HardikShekhat, what have you tried according to that answer?

Comment: ohhh k k friend.. So handle it through code that is the solution.

Comment: @S.Karthik. Right but how to handle it. plz give me solution for that.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, did you check Settings -> Display and brightness -> View (Standart)?

Comment: plz give me proper path. Which Settings Xcode or iOS Simulator. In both Xcode or iOS Simulator I can't find it.

Comment: this option is in iPhone (device properly)

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible patch to identify your screen type is by getting the scale of your screen. You can use the following code : `[UIScreen mainScreen].scale;`

This will not let you know the exact screen size but will allow you to know what is the scaling. This method might be helpful where you need not to code individually for different screens and majorly do not want to convert your entire code to autolayout.

To know the scaling factor of different screens refer to following link : http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/iphone-6-screens-demystified

Comment: Thanks but not woking. In iPhone 6+ it gives 3.0 it is right but for iPhone 6 and iPhone 5s it gives scale 2.0. So can't identify device is iPhone 6 or iPhone 5s.