# Why UIScreen mainScreen bounds size returns 568 for iPhone6 device?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscreen

I am getting 568p as screen height and scale factor 2x both for iPhone 5 and iPhone 6 [ios 9.2.1]. Why it is returning 568p instead of 667p for iPhone 6?

Device: iPhone (only)
Device Orientation: Portrait only
Launch Images:

> Default.png  Default@2x.png  Default-568h@2x.png  Default-667h@2x.png Default-736h@3x.png

*Edit: Marked Duplicate question does not fully address my case. In that case, Launch Image for 4 inch screen was not added and so that app was running in 3.5 inch compatible mode. For this case, I have added all Launch Images, tried asset catalog, but no luck.*

Comment: It is possible that you app is running in [Compatibility mode](http://mackuba.eu/2015/02/17/making-ios-apps-compatible-with-iphone6/)? Have you added the proper launch screens?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21668497/uiscreen-mainscreen-bounds-returning-wrong-size

Comment: @MargaretBloom App is built for  iPhone  only and it already has proper launch screens. still same problem

Comment: Goto Setting -> Display & Brightness -> View ->Standard

Run again

Comment: @AshishThummar zoom display mode is alrady Standard mode.

Comment: @DareDevil Please add Default-736h@3x.png May will work.

Comment: @AshishThummar still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Please set all the required images in asset catalog

[image]

or if you are using iOS8 and above then use LaunchScreen.xib

Comment: Tried asset catalog but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you getting this output but its should return 667.0 I have also try this and you can see result in screen shot.

[image]

if you getting screen resolution of subviews of the iPhone 6 so you should put all the splash screen in Assets.

Comment: Tried asset catalog but no luck.