# UIScreen mainScreen bounds give wrong size

Tags: ios, frame

Hi i am initiate a rootViewController programatically (portal only no landscape]

this is the code use

```
CGRect appFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
```

But it does not give correct size. (cut down at bottom screen)

Only this code give correct

```
 CGRect appFrame = [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame
```

But this code will give warning of depreciated (applicationFrame is depreciated)

(My simulator is IOS 9.3)

How to fix the problem? any help is much appreciate! thanks!

here is screenshoot when using `[UIscreen mainscreen].bounds`

[image]

and here is [UIscreen mainscreen].applicationFrame

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do the following.

```
CGRect rect = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;

CGRect screenFrame = CGRectMake(0, [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame].size.height, rect.size.width, rect.size.height - [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame].size.height);
```

Now you can use this screenFrame, I hope this will resolve your problem.

Comment: Hi do we need to minus rect.size.height - [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame].size.height. I found same result when using only rect.size.height. is that correct?

Comment: yes because, it will take you screen [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame].size.height down, so without decreasing the lower portion of the screen will be clipped.

Comment: Thanks! the bounds include status bar so we need some calculation to get actual frame from the bounds

Comment: great you found the solution :)

Answer (score 3):

`[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]` gives the correct size of the entire window, but it includes the size of the status bar. If you want the size of the status bar ( you can subtract its height), you should use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame]` to get the frame of the status bar. Navigation bars and tab bars generally have a height of 44. So, use `CGRectMake()` if you need a rectangle for your view:

```
CGRect frame_screen = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGRect frame_view = CGRectMake(0,0,frame_screen.size.width,frame_screen.size.height - [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame].size.height);
```

Notice that the last argument of `CGRectMake` is the height, usually you can minus 44 for a tab bar or navigation bar.

EDIT: Try to log `[UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame` and `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]` to console and see what the difference is between them. Something like

```
CGRect frame_screen = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
NSLog(@"x: %f, y: %f, width: %f, height: %f",frame_screen.origin.x,frame_screen.origin.y,frame_screen.size.width,frame_screen.size.height);
CGRect frame_application = [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame
NSLog(@"x: %f, y: %f, width: %f, height: %f",frame_application.origin.x,frame_application.origin.y,frame_application.size.width,frame_application.size.height);
```

Then use that information to make `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds` frame how you need it.

Comment: Hi using your suggestion i still get the cut down at bottom. may be need some calculation of the starting 0,0 because cut down at bottom not on top

Comment: dont know why i need to move the Y direction like this to make correct one CGRect appFrame = CGRectMake(0,[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame].size.height,frame_screen.size.width,frame_screen.size.height - [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame].size.height);

Comment: Could you put a screenshot in your question? I don't think I quite understand what the problem is. Maybe you could add some more code to the question?

Comment: Hi i add screen shoot for. there is a gap at bottom up use bounds

Comment: Have you added launch screen for your app? Which simulator you are running it?

Comment: I edited the answer to try and help you find a way to solve the problem.

Comment: Hi both log provide same result: 2016-08-05 02:39:23.896 SingPost[17516:195253] x: 0.000000, y: 0.000000, width: 320.000000, height: 568.000000
2016-08-05 02:39:23.896 SingPost[17516:195253] x: 0.000000, y: 0.000000, width: 320.000000, height: 568.000000

Comment: I am doing by     CGRect appFrame = CGRectMake(0,[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame].size.height,frame_screen.size.width,frame_screen.size.height);
but dont know why that work

Comment: That code looks good to me. x is measured from the left of the screen, and y is measured from the top.

Comment: Hi do you think my solution is correct! why same log with CGRect provide different outcome

Comment: I changed the debugging code a bit and tested it, application frame prints a y of 20.00000, So your code makes sense and it is correct

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have added all resolution splash image on yous's application **Images.xcassets**
`

> Please take a look on Screen shot i attached

` [image]

> CGRect appFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]; //This is the
>   correct way to get your screen size

Comment: Hi this is my original launchImage: https://postimg.org/image/tow29iwnr/

Comment: When try add 1 more set i got these huge category. do we need to add add? https://postimg.org/image/91dedwqgh/

Comment: launch image is not related to this question.

Comment: @SurbhiGarg apparently it is, there is a related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21668497/uiscreen-mainscreen-bounds-returning-wrong-size

Comment: @JonathanChen I have not asked the question, just down vote question or make it duplicate, don't just point out me.